# Google Script not running sequentially

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having trouble with some creating some functions in Google Script. I'm trying to query a range then copy and paste it's values, however it doesn't seem to load even when I put a sleep timer in between. It does, however run when I comment out the copy and paste.

Any help is appreciated!

```
function setAndCopy(sheetName){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange("B3:P").clearContent();
  var targetCell = sheet.getRange("B3");
  var formulaString = "=query(Vehicles!A2:AM,\"Select A,B,C,D,E,K where E<>''\")";

  targetCell.setFormula(formulaString);

  Utilities.sleep(10000);

  sheet.getRange("B3:P").copyTo(sheet.getRange("B3:P"),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` after setting the formula.

```
function setAndCopy(sheetName){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange("B3:P").clearContent();
  var targetCell = sheet.getRange("B3");
  var formulaString = "=query(Vehicles!A2:AM,\"Select A,B,C,D,E,K where E<>''\")";

  targetCell.setFormula(formulaString);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  Utilities.sleep(10000);

  sheet.getRange("B3:P").copyTo(sheet.getRange("B3:P"),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```